# Is it possible for most (all?) items in a list to lie within one standard deviation of the mean of that list?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, computer-science, integers, descriptive-statistics

**Question.** Is it possible for most (all?) items of a list to lie within one standard deviation of the mean of that list?

**Motivation.** Fast computations of approximate medians of lists of integers is considered an important problem in computer science. My personal interest in the problem comes from the fact that if a quicksort implementation uses a good approximations to the median for choosing its pivot elements, the worst-case time complexity will be $O(n \log n)$, which is considered fast.

With that motivation established, recall that the *nonparametric skew* of a distribution is defined as $$\frac{\mu - \nu}{\sigma},$$ where $\mu$ is the mean, $\nu$ is the median, and $\sigma$ is the standard deviation. According to [the relevant wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonparametric_skew):

> The nonparametric skew ... lies between $-1$ and $+1$ for any distribution

Obviously, this applies to lists as well, and not just probability distributions. Therefore, I'm interested in using this to quickly find the median of a list $L$ of not-necessarily positive integers. Here's the idea: if the standard deviation of $L$ is zero, the first item of the list is the median. Otherwise, we can omit elements that aren't one standard deviation of the mean, recalculate $\mu$ and $\sigma$, and repeat the process. A related idea is to stop after a certain portion of the list items have been omitted by this process, in the hope that a randomly chosen element of the remaining elements will provide a good approximation to the median.

Here's the problem: the process of omitting elements needs to be guaranteed to omit a decent portion of the list at each iteration. Otherwise, the worst-case time complexity of this strategy will be very bad. Indeed, if there exist lists in which all the points are within one standard deviation of the mean, the aforementioned algorithm will never terminate for those lists.

Comment: Doesn't that depend on the process that generates the values? For e.g., pick average $\mu$ and std deviation $\sigma$ and generate random values that lie within $\mu \pm \sigma$. If you sampled from this process, **all** values will lie within the interval. If you did the opposite, i.e., discarded random values in the interval and took random values outside the interval, then that sample will have no entries in the $\mu \pm \sigma$ range.

Comment: @vvg You can pick numbers you *call* $\mu$ and $\sigma$ and generate random values within $\mu \pm \sigma$, but the standard deviation of the values you generate won't be $\sigma$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov: You are right. What I meant to say was, if the process was gaussian, then we could only expect around 68% of the samples will be within 1 standard deviation.

Comment: answer: no. the standard deviation is determined by how dispersed the data is.

Comment: Replying to the comments: you're imagining that there's an ambient process with its own $\mu$ and $\sigma$ that's produced our list, and we're going to use the $\mu$ and $\sigma$ of this process to sort the list. My intention is the opposite: rather, we think of $L$ as a probability distribution (obtained by choosing an index $i$ uniformly at random and returning $L[i]$), and exploit the theorem in the wikipedia article to conclude that $\mu(L)$ and $\nu(L)$ are within a distance of $\sigma(L)$ from each other. The process that created $L$ isn't actually relevant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In a degenerate case, it's possible: in a list of integers which has only two values $a$ and $b$, appearing equally often, the mean will be $\frac{a+b}{2}$ and the (population) standard deviation will be $\frac{|a-b|}{2}$, and both values will be within a standard deviation of the mean.

We can prove that this is the only situation in which this happens (for a probability distribution). If $\Pr[|X-\mu| \le \sigma] = 1$, then $\Pr[(X-\mu)^2 \le \sigma^2] = 1$, so the random variable $(X-\mu)^2$ must almost surely be at most its expected value: $\sigma^2$, by definition. This can only happen if it's almost surely *equal* to its expected value $\sigma^2$, so we must have $X \in \{\mu-\sigma, \mu+\sigma\}$ with probability $1$.

---

More concerning are situations where *most* values lie within a standard deviation of the mean, which can happen easily when the data has extreme outliers. We might hope that in the outlined median-finding algorithm, one phase will get rid of outliers, and then the next phase will work much better. But I can imagine scenarios where that won't happen.

For example, consider the following data set of $2n+1$ elements,  with mean and median $0$:
$$
   -2^{2^n}, -2^{2^{n-1}}, -2^{2^{n-2}}, \dots, -2^{2^1}, 0, 2^{2^1}, \dots, 2^{2^{n-2}}, 2^{2^{n-1}}, 2^{2^n}.
$$
(Here, $f(x) = 2^{2^x}$ is just one possible extremely fast-growing function.)

The extreme values $\pm 2^{2^n}$ are so large that they make the standard deviation extremely large, which means that all other values fall within a standard deviation of the mean. So the algorithm will drop those two extremes from our data set, and leave the other $2n-1$ values. But then, we're on the $n-1$ case of the same pattern, and the same behavior happens again; it takes $O(n)$ phases to identify the median of $0$.

Whether this is likely or not depends on the kind of distribution your numbers come from.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to ponder this. I assume that last bit is basically saying $X \in B_\sigma(\mu)$ or something to that effect? I guess one viewpoint here is that $\pm$ is somewhat overloaded in mathematics, sometimes meaning $\pm x = \{-x,x\}$, other times meaning $\pm x = [-x,-x]$ and/or $(-x,x)$.

Comment: In your degenerate case all the points are exactly $1$ standard deviation from the mean.  Whether this is "*within* one standard deviation" depends on your use of language.

Comment: @SocraticMathTutor I've clarified my meaning: $X$ is either $\mu-\sigma$ or $\mu+\sigma$.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'm not sure I quite get the last part of the argument, but I've given you the green checkmark.

Comment: @SocraticMathTutor For more details along these lines, look up [Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality). The fact about the mean and median is [one application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#An_application:_distance_between_the_mean_and_the_median) of the inequality, and my argument is essentially the proof of Chebyshev's inequality, run in reverse.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible for most (all?) items of a list to lie within one standard deviation of the mean of that list?

It is absolutely *possible* for most items of a list to be within $\sigma$ of the mean.  How *likely* that is depends on what you mean by "most".  Details are a function of the discrete distribution your list represents, but if, say, it approximates a sample from a normal distribution then you would expect about two thirds of the list elements to be within $\sigma$ of the mean.  There are plenty of other ways in which the same proportion or more of the list elements could be within $\sigma$ of the mean.

To gauge the potential power of your approach, it might also be useful to look at how much you could expect to reduce the search space for the median when the data have other kinds of distributions.  In particular, if the distribution of your elements is approximately uniform, then you can still expect more than half of them (around 58%) to be within $\sigma$ of the mean.

Comment: Is there a name or standard notation for the distribution that a list "represents" as you call it? The idea seems to be pretty standard and quite useful. Indeed, although the relative frequency tables they force us to build in high school are usually explained as approximations to the distributions that produced the data, they could easily well be explained as exact descriptions of the distribution of elements obtained by choosing indices in the list uniformly at random, which is imo a fairly natural thing to do.

Comment: @SocraticMathTutor, I am not aware of a name or standard notation for the concept of the distribution of a list of numbers other than "the distribution of a list of numbers".  You are quite right, though, that for finite, discrete distributions such as these, it is possible to write frequency tables that describe the distribution exactly.